# how to hide site url in facebook when share page?

Tags: facebook, url, share

when i use comment facebook plugin, then i'm comment in my site page. in my facebook timeline, i see
picture, title, url site, and description.
How to hide that's url site on facebook timeline ?

i'm not wrote `<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>` there.

my code show below:

`<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo trim($title); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $desc;?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $url_pic; ?>"/>`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can ommit the description but for users safety I dont think you can hide the sites url. it will allways be parsed from the page plugin is in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the Site URL when sharing links on Facebook. It's a security feature so users know what domain they will be visiting.